# Wordpress Multisite Main Network Admin Login Loop

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, multisite

I have a wordpress multisite install, which once upon a time worked absolutely fine. Recently I haven't been able to access the main network admin dashboard. I am presented with the wordpress login screen again and when I put the details in, it redirects back to the log in screen.

I thought it was a problem with either the HTACCESS or the WP CONFIG. I cant see what would have changed.

I have tried the clearing cookies, running in incognito mode, disabling security plugins that write to the htaccess, and trying suggested define() scripts in the config file.

**Htaccess:**

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

# add a trailing slash to /wp-admin
RewriteRule ^wp-admin$ wp-admin/ [R=301,L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]
RewriteRule ^(wp-(content|admin|includes).*) $1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*\.php)$ $1 [L]
RewriteRule . index.php [L]
```

wp-config snippet

```
define('WP_DEBUG', false);

/* Multisite */
define('MULTISITE', true);
define('SUBDOMAIN_INSTALL', true);
define('DOMAIN_CURRENT_SITE', 'dwml.co.uk');
define('PATH_CURRENT_SITE', '/');
define('SITE_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);
define('BLOG_ID_CURRENT_SITE', 1);

define('COOKIE_DOMAIN', $_SERVER[ 'HTTP_HOST' ] );
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What URL is it redirected you back to? Does it have any parameters at all or an error message?

Comment: try to comment the multisite plugin or check this link http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-install-and-setup-wordpress-multisite-network/ for htaccess or wp-config file. 

is there any error while login? but your both files seems fine. Maybe you can change your login credentials.

Comment: The query string being returned is ?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fdwml.co.uk%2Fwp-admin%2Fnetwork%2F&reauth=1 I am not receiving any log in errors and I can access single site dashbaords individually, just not the main overall network admin area.